# Radial Basis Function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am trying to make a simple radial basis function network (RBFN) for regression. I have a 20 dimensional (feature) dataset with over 600 samples. I need the final network to output 1 scalar value for each 20 dimensional sample.

Note: new to machine learning...and feel like I am missing an important concept here.

With the perceptron we can, and I have, trained a linear network until the prediction error is at a minimum using a small subset of the initial samples.

Is there a similar process with the RBFN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is,

The main two differences between a multi-layer perceptron and a RBFN are the fact that a RBFN usually implies just one layer and that the activation function is a gaussian instead of a sigmoid.

The training phase can be done using gradient descend of the error loss function, so it is relatively simple to implement.

Keep in mind that RBFN is a linear combination of RBF units, so the range of the output is limited and you would need to transform it if you need an scalar outside of that range.

There is a few of resources that you could consult as reference:

[PDF] (http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-6197-223641/unrestricted/Ch3.pdf)

[Wikipedia] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network)

[Wolfram]  (http://reference.wolfram.com/applications/neuralnetworks/NeuralNetworkTheory/2.5.2.html)

Hope it helps,